# Java (JRE 1.7.45) not working Internet Explorer 11 and webtop 6.7 applets

Tags: java, internet-explorer-11, jre, java-applet, documentum

I can't get Java to work on IE 11 for an intranet site (Documentum Webtop 6.7), so far I've:

- Enable Java in browser in Java Control Panel.
- Set security to medium in Java Control Panel.
- On user tab select the Java 1.7.45 x86 to be the one active.
- Enable Scripting of Java Applets on IE settings>security
- Lowered the privacy on IE untilit shows “Accept all cookies”
- Restored security prompts on Java Control Panel
- Enable several Active X options on IE
- Deleted the “%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\VersionManager\versionlist.xml”
- Disable Active X filtering for the intranet zone.
- I've browse to the JRE/bin folder and java.exe/javaw.exe/javaws.exe are there and seems to work when running them from CMD.
- All from this blog post (actually I got the same error): https://simplydocumentum.blogspot.com/2017/07/solved-error-browser-does-not-support.html

But still IE seems to ignore Java got installed, when opening a java applet from the webtop application (documentum) I only get the message "Your browser does not support Java" (not native browser message,  this came from the webtop application) just like the one in this blog post: https://simplydocumentum.blogspot.com/2017/07/solved-error-browser-does-not-support.html

The only clue I have is that when user open up my webex room link, she actually got a bar notification on IE saying "java was blocked because it is out of date" with 2 buttons, update/run this time only, but I don't get any warning/prompt when accessing the intranet web application.

IE version: 11.0.9600.19339 update 11.0.135
Windows 7 64bits.
JRE installed in control panel I see 1.7.45 and 1.7.11

My next step is to remove all JRE and re-install 1.7.45 but not clue if would it work, I'm not certain this would it have any effect, any other suggestion ?

**Update 8/8/2019**
After uninstalling all Java versions and re-installing only Java 1.7.45 (32bits), a different user got Java working on the intranet site (after enabling unsigned Active X, compatibility view for the site and setting Java security to medium in Java  control panel.

These discard machine/network related stuff, now I we will check with the user having the issue to verify if the java re-install did something for her.

**Update 2 8/18/2019**
It work, just like that on the user's account who reported the issue first. I can't tell what was the exact issue but after doing the uninstall/install ritual, Java started to prompt by security confirmations and stuff and I just had to allow it to run. (maybe versions of the same main branch 1.7 were conflicting among them, not idea)

Comment: Is there a reason your using such an old version of the JRE 7?  It’s literally more than 2 years old.

Comment: It is the latest that it is supposed to still work with the app, although I've noticed my JRE is set to 1.8 when in java console when I open the app, but at this point Java version seems not to be the actual issue (other user is using same IE/Java combination)

Comment: Try hints described in answers to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21145293/9709361

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the author solved the problem.